# Is ‘pure exponential sum’ not an item of standard terminology?

Tags: reference-request

I see articles using this expression, but I’m having difficulty finding a formal definition of it. Is it just a colloquialism?

edit: here's an example of its use:
http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa91/aa9136.pdf

Comment: I’ve never heard it, nor have I seen it. Is this a special branch of mathematics, or of science?

Comment: Neither have I, nor Wikipedia, it seems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_sum#Types_of_exponential_sum  I would have considered *uniform* or *standard* versus *weighted* sums, but I am no specialist.